# Como gerar o arquivo jar pelo maven?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Eu preciso gerar um arquivo jar na pasta do projeto como mostra a imagem abaixo;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não quero ficar dependendo do comando bash  **mvn clean install**, eu gostaria muito de colocar as configurações no arquivo pom.xml para quando a aplicação for executada ele automaticamente ele gere o arquivo .jar na pasta do projeto web.

Se trata de um projeto Spring Boot, porém as configurações que coloquei abaixo não funcionaram e preciso saber como acertar o código;

```
<build>
<finalName>dockerTest</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: O Maven serve para gerenciamento de dependências e configurações sobre empacotamento, para você ter o jar o Maven vai ser responsável por gerá-lo. Não tem como você utilizar o Maven e não rodar a goal de geração de artefatos. Sugiro a leitura da documentação da ferramenta, porque acredito que seu entendimento sobre o funcionamento dela esteja equivocado.

Answer (score 1):

Uma correção: não é um comando `bash`, é um comando. Simples assim. Poderia ser executado na Bourne Shell, Dash, Ash, Csh, Zsh, Cmd, PowerShell, até mesmo ser chamado dentro do Ruby usando `tiques`.

Em outro lado, o Eclipse fornece para você uma facilidade de rodar comandos Maven. Uma alternativa é:

- clique com o botão direito sobre o seu projeto
- selecione "Debug As" (eu prefiro o "debug" porque é mais provável chamar a JDK do que a JRE)
- então selecione "Maven build..."
- coloque seus `goals` desejados

[image: botão direito sobre o projeto]

[image: selecione "maven build"]

[image: coloque seus "goals"]

Após fazer isso, fica o atalho nos últimos "runs":

[image: acesso rápido ao debug]

> note que usar as opções previamente disponíveis mostradas pelo menu de contexto do Eclipse, como "Maven install" ou "Maven clean", não deixa o atalho disponível

Outras IDEs também permitem que você faça chamadas desse tipo, mas eu aconselho aprender mais sobre as opções de linha de comando do Maven; em ambientes de CI/CD, você terá acesso à linha de comando crua normalmente em um YAML, e em projetos que crescem bastante essas opções se tornam mais úteis.